# How to get custom roles enabled for an user in office 365 environment from powerapps

Tags: office365, powerapps

How to get custom roles that were enabled for a user from office 365 environment. We are trying to hide/display buttons/fields in power apps by custom roles of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. In [PowerApps admin center](https://admin.powerapps.com/) select the environment where you want to update a security role.
2. Click on the link in Details tab to manage the environment in Dynamics 365 admin center.
3. Select the instance (with the same name of environment) and click on Open.
4. In the header, click on the Settings and select Security.
5. Select Security roles.
6. Click on New.
7. From the security role designer, you select the actions, such as read, write, or delete, and the scope for performing that action.
8. Select the tab and search for your entity e.g. Custom Entities tab, for setting permissions on a custom entity.
9. Select the privileges Read, Write, Append
10. List item

For more information, please review the following link:

[Create or configure a custom security role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/administrator/database-security#create-or-configure-a-custom-security-role)

Comment: Above steps are for configuring security. My question is about accessing the configured custom roles from powerapps. How do we get handle to roles that were enabled for an user ?

Answer (score 0):

The most sufficient method is to create Azure AD Groups having Graph API capability that could read and write organization user roles. After that, we can create a custom connector in PowerApps and use only defined roles or users to have certain views.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by,
1. Create SharePoint List having role wise users in SharePoint site.
2. While OnStart/OnVisible of Screen, Microsoft flow can be triggered.
3. Microsoft flow will contains logic to get Role Name based on current login user.
4. Based on returned Role, Button/Fields can be hide/show in Power apps screen.